# End to end encryption in mobile banking?

Tags: ssh, banks, end-to-end-encryption

Can we use E2EE to secure the communication between the bank and it's customers in the applications of mobile banking? And what is the status off E2EE vs SSH regarding this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we use E2EE to secure the communication between the bank and it's customers in the applications of mobile banking?

We do. We commonly use TLS for securing communication, and this is a end to end encryption, between the phone and the banks servers. You can recognize TLS in use by the use of https:// in such URLs. Most apps as well tend to use TLS encryption for data.

> and what the status off e2ee vs SSH regarding this matter?

End to end encryption is a concept. SSH is a protocol. SSH implements end to end encryption. So can https, or any other number of protocols with encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about E2EE makes sense only in cases where there are 3+ systems involved, i.e. when your data go through intermediary systems until it reaches the final intentented end. You dont want the data decrypted in any intermediary system. Only the end system knows how to decrypt the data, and all intermediary systems deal with encrypted data, unaware of the content.
But in your case, you have just the 2 ends, your mobile and the bank's site. There is no intermediary system. So with TLS you have E2EE.

Comment: The Internet is a system of intermediary systems. Definitions of EE2E are not strictly about end user to end user encryption (which is what I think you meant): https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/end-to-end-encryption-E2EE